# Select row with maximum value from table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, top-n

I have a table with non-unique column auth_id. I need to select the auth_id value with maximum number of entries.

```
SELECT auth_id, cnt
FROM (SELECT auth_id, COUNT(auth_id) AS cnt 
FROM articles_authors 
GROUP BY auth_id) articles_num
WHERE cnt = (SELECT MAX(articles_num.cnt))
```

Here's the data example:

```
auth_id    article_id
1              2
1              1
1              3
2              2
3              1
3              2
```

And the output:

```
auth_id    cnt
1           3
```

But SQL doesn't see the alias table articles_num.
How do I make this WHERE clause with this alias?

Comment: provide some sample data and expected result out of those.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `limit` clause would be much simpler - you simply order a query according to some field, and then just take the first row:

```
SELECT   auth_id, COUNT(auth_id) AS cnt 
FROM     articles_authors 
GROUP BY auth_id
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT    1
```

Comment: This works, but what if we have many auth_id with maximum entries?

Answer (score 1):

Order your data in descending order in your inner query then just take the first one:

```
SELECT auth_id, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT auth_id, COUNT(auth_id) AS cnt 
    FROM articles_authors 
    GROUP BY auth_id 
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
     )
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you actually want to get one row of the max of the count:

```
SELECT auth_id, count(auth_id) as cnt
FROM articles_authors
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If more than one auth_id have same max count, we need to update this SQL

Answer (score 0):

Try this.......

```
select auth_id, count(auth_id) as cnt 
from articles_authors 
group by auth_id 
order by cnt DESC 
limit 1;
```

Let me know if it resolves your issue